# How do I find this limit? $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{4^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{4^n}$$ The answer says zero is the limit, how this is I do not understand, I've tried H'opitals rule , didn;t work out for me, anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this limit ?

Comment: L'Hopital's rule should work. Can you show your work?

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule works fine. For computing convenience note that $(n+1)^2/4^n \lt (n+1)^2/e^n$.

Comment: Are you even allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By l'Hospital's rule, you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{4^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n+1)}{4^n\cdot\log 4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{4^n(\log 4)^2}=\frac{2}{(\log 4)^2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}=0.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Observe that 
$$
(n+1)^2\le 2^{n+2}
$$
For every natural number $n$, then observe that
$$
0\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{4^n}\le\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+2}}{4^n}=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you denote the sequence in the limit to be $a_n$, how does $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ behave? What does it tell you about behavior of the sequence?